A reference for an equation of evolution for a probability measure
I assume that there exist a family of probability measures $(d\mu_{t})_{t\geq 0}$ over the circle $\mathbb{R}_{|2\pi\mathbb{Z}}$ satisfying the following equation of evolution: for every continuous test function $f\in\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}_{|2\pi\mathbb{Z}},\mathbb{R})$:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)d\mu_t(x)\right)=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\sin(x-x') d\mu_t(x)d\mu_t(x').$$
Do someone know if this kind of equation has already been studied?

Just curious, can you please explain where did it come from?

Thanks for your interest. In the following article: 10.1103/PhysRevE.85.051903 , a high number of interacting particles are moving over 3 (or 4) sites, preserving the global mass (the number of particles). I'm trying to generalize this system to a continuum of sites, represented by the circle. The distribution of particles at time $t$ is represented by the probability measure $d\mu_t$
